# SBPL -can't find package

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, sbpl, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, after installing all the packages connected with [Dwa_local_planner](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation), including those:

```
http://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_msgs (new in Jade+)
http://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_tutorials
http://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental
```

I have errors after catkin_make:

```
By not providing "FindSBPL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SBPL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SBPL" with any of
  the following names:

    SBPLConfig.cmake
    sbpl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SBPL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SBPL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SBPL"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323552/sbpl---can%27t-find-package/) by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-20**:
Can you please clarify why you are trying to install these packages by compiling them from source in your Catkin workspace instead of using the released binaries (and `apt`)?

**Comment by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on 2019-05-20**:
I made git clone ...
Should I use sudo apt-get?
I don't understand the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which packages do you want to install? Just the names, no `git` repositories.

Packages which have been released have binary `.deb` packages available. There is no need to compile those yourself. Typically.

> after installing all the packages connected with Dwa_local_planner, including those:

> ```
> http://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_msgs (new in Jade+)
> ```

```
http://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_tutorials
http://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental
```

You write "installing", but I believe you mean `git clone`-ing (into your Catkin workspace).

For `dwa_local_planner` specifically, that would seem to be unnecessary: [wiki/dwa_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner?distro=kinetic). Note how it says `Released` and `Documented` under the `Package Summary` heading.

A simple `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ros-kinetic-dwa-local-planner` should suffice.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on 2019-05-20**:
Okey then, I won't use catkin_make. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the following:

sudo apt install ros-noetic-sbpl-*